# Visitor cookie on siteA in order to segment user type in Google Analytics data on siteB

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-analytics

I have two types of users coming to siteB(contractors & consumers). I know for a fact that if a user visits SiteA, they are a contractor because there's a contractor only login. I want to run a cookie on SiteA for all visitors so that when they come to SiteB I can read that cookie and segment or filter out contractors from consumers in my Google Analytics data. Can anyone help me out with the code for this?

Yes, I own both sites.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use your own cookie (which will not work across domains anyway). Instead

- set up a session level custom dimension with a value of contracter at site SiteA
- Set up Cross Domain Tracking between SiteA and SiteB (which you want to do anyway if you expect traffic between sites)
- Google will allow you to segment by custom dimenson and filter out those visits where the custom dimension is set.

For that to work both sites need to be tracked with the same Google Analytics property.

If that is not the case then simply add a url parameter to all links from SiteA to SiteB and set a custom dimension for segmentation based on that (will of course only work for user who go directly from one page to the other).